# Cambios en el body desde jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo un problema ya que Google me indica que el contenido es más ancho que la pantalla y que por lo tanto hay que hacer scroll para ver todo el contenido.

Mi solución pasa por hacer una función jquery donde busque si el dipositivo es móvil.

Le aplique al `body` un `overflow hidden` y que por lo tanto no se salga nada de la pantalla.
Pero no estoy seguro de que la función este bien del todo.

```
if($.browser.device = (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))){
    $('body').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
}
```

Comment: Qué versión de jQuery estás usando? recuerda que `browser` fue [removido](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) en versiones más recientes y es poco recomendable su uso.

Answer (score 0):

Según la [**documentación**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/):

> *English: Contains flags for the useragent, read from navigator.userAgent. This property was **removed in jQuery 1.9** and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.*
>
> *Español: Contiene indicadores para el agente de usuario, leídos desde navigator.userAgent. Esta propiedad **se eliminó en jQuery 1.9** y solo está disponible a través del complemento jQuery.migrate. Intente utilizar la detección de características en su lugar.*

La propiedad `browser` fue removida en versiones recientes de jQuery. Entonces, tu validación podría quedar de esta forma:

```
if(/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    $('body').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
}
```

O podrías utilizar la regla [**`@media`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) de CSS para indicar que ocurran ciertas propiedades al superar el `px` que le indiques:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```